# UIView performance: opaque, backgroundColor, clearsContextBeforeDrawing?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, uiview, uikit

I'm displaying opaque PNGs with `UIImageView`s inside of a superview with a white background color. What's best for performance?

#### `UIImageView` Defaults

`opaque = NO`, `backgroundColor = nil`, `clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES`.

#### [iOS Developer Library: `UIView` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

1. [UIView Class Reference: backgroundColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/backgroundColor) says, "[`nil`] results in a transparent background color." If I set a [`UIView`s `opaque` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/opaque) to `YES`, must I also set its `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`, or is that extra line of code & processing unnecessary? I.e., is `[UIColor clearColor]` considered opaque (not transparent)?
2. Does the value of `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` matter for opaque views?

   The comments for `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` in `UIView.h` say it's ignored for opaque views.

   But, [UIView Class Reference: clearsContextBeforeDrawing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clearsContextBeforeDrawing) says:

   > If the view’s `opaque` property is also set to `YES`, the `backgroundColor` property of
   >   the view must not be `nil` or drawing errors may occur.

   Which is it?

#### Similar Questions

- [Is UIView's opaque property with a value of YES in conflict with its backgroundColor property with a value of [UIColor clearColor]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102663/is-uiviews-opaque-property-with-a-value-of-yes-in-conflict-with-its-backgroundc)
- [Cocoa/iPhone: BackgroundColor and Opaque Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524785/cocoa-iphone-backgroundcolor-and-opaque-properties)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that your PNGs always fills the entire `UIImageView`, you should get the best performance using:

`opaque = YES`, `clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO`. In this mode `backgroundColor` is irrelevant. The pixels are simply replaced with the new image data.

For transparent PNGs on a single-color background, the fastest will be:

`opaque = YES`, `clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES`, and `backgroundColor` matching whatever you need. In this case `[UIColor whiteColor]`.

Comment: Thanks, and what if my PNGs have transparency?

Comment: Ah, you said they were opaque, i.e. non-transparent, which is what I answered. I'll edit my answer with for transparent PNGs.

Comment: Nice, and what if my background is multi-colored?

Comment: Then you should probably use the default settings.

Answer (score 3):

If you set UIView's opaque property to YES, you must ensure your drawing completely fills the view with no transparency. So, you need to set a white background colour (a clear one won't work, because that's not opaque).

I don't think you want to change the defaults for your image view, but you should ensure that your PNGs do not have any transparency (that is, have no alpha channel; you can check this in Preview's image inspector; ensure it doesn't say 'Has Alpha'.). I believe UIImageView will do the right thing if you give it an opaque image.

Depending on what's in the background, you might get better performance with opaque = YES and a white background for your image views, (to prevent redrawing parts of the parent view) but I wouldn't start that way.