# What's the relationship among opaque, alpha, and backgroundColor of a UIView?

Tags: ios, performance, uiview, alpha

For example:

1. I set UIView's alpha property as `alpha = 0`, Does that means its `opaque` property be treated as `opaque=YES`?
2. How `opaque`，`alpha` and `backgroundColor` affect the performance?
3. Anything else?...

#### Similar Questions

- [UIView performance: opaque, backgroundColor, clearsContextBeforeDrawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017923/uiview-performance-opaque-backgroundcolor-clearscontextbeforedrawing)
- [Is UIView's opaque property with a value of YES in conflict with its backgroundColor property with a value of [UIColor clearColor]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102663/is-uiviews-opaque-property-with-a-value-of-yes-in-conflict-with-its-backgroundc)
- [Cocoa/iPhone: BackgroundColor and Opaque Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524785/cocoa-iphone-backgroundcolor-and-opaque-properties)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`backgroundColor` is the color that appears in the back of a `UIView`. By default, it's `nil`, resulting in a clear background color for the `UIView`. To assign a background to your `UIView`, assign a `UIColor` like so:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

You can also set the `backgroundColor` to be an image:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"myImage"]];
```

---

`alpha` is the opacity of the view. You can use this attribute to fade a `UIView` and make it partially transparent. The value can range from 0 (completely invisible) to 1 (completely opaque).

---

`opaque` is a boolean value that indicates whether the `UIView` is opaque or not. If you've set the `alpha` to anything less than 1, then you should set `opaque` to NO:

```
myView.opaque = NO;
```

Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/opaque) explains why and how the `opaque` property works:

> This property provides a hint to the drawing system as to how it
>   should treat the view. If set to YES, the drawing system treats the
>   view as fully opaque, which allows the drawing system to optimize some
>   drawing operations and improve performance. If set to NO, the drawing
>   system composites the view normally with other content. The default
>   value of this property is YES.
>
> An opaque view is expected to fill its bounds with entirely opaque
>   content—that is, the content should have an alpha value of 1.0. If the
>   view is opaque and either does not fill its bounds or contains wholly
>   or partially transparent content, the results are unpredictable. You
>   should always set the value of this property to NO if the view is
>   fully or partially transparent.

Comment: nice reply. 

it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

**opaque meaning:**

not transparent

**transparency meaning:**

see throughness,not opaque

**alpha meaning:**

The inventors of RGBA model named alpha after the Greek letter in the classic linear interpolation formula `αA + (1-α)B`

To understand we can assume alpha is synonym for opaque in this graphic and image context.

**Relation between opaque,transparency and alpha:**

opaque is directly propotional to alpha 
and inversely propotional to transparency
i.e 
increase in alpha value results in increase in opaque and and decrease transparency

if alpha is 1.0 for a view then it's completely opaque

if alpha is 0.0 for a view then it's completely transparent..

**relation between opaque,alpha and backgroundcolor:**

he alpha will also affect the alpha of the backround color i.e. if the background color is 0.5 transparent and the alpha is also 0.5, this has the effect of making the background view's alpha 0.25 (0.5 * 0.5)

**Opaque perfomance:**

if u set opaque as YES then there is a increase in performance because blending is not gonna take place with underlying view or color